# No value for uninitialized NumericValue object for a Variable[t]- Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo, glpk

I am new to Pyomo and trying to find a way to optimize my battery algorithm with undefined battery capacity (Smax) and inverter size (Rmax).

My objective is to find the combinaison of Smax and Rmax that minimize the total charging costs of the battery.

But I get this error:
"No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Ein[0]"

Here is my code:

#####################################################################

```
       model = ConcreteModel()

       # Define model parameters
       model.T = Set(doc='hour of the period', initialize=df.hour.tolist(), ordered=True)
       model.Rmax = Var( within=PositiveIntegers )
       model.Smax = Var( within=PositiveIntegers )
       model.Ein = Var(model.T, bounds = (0, None))   " Energy charged in battery at period t"
       model.Eout = Var(model.T, bounds = (0, None))   "Energy discharged from battery at period t"
       model.Z = Var(model.T, bounds = (0, None))   "Energy stored in battery at the end of the hour 
       model.L = Var(model.T)  "Energy bought from the grid at every period t"


   # DEFINE ALL CONSTRAINTS OF THE MODEL

   "Initial storage state = 0 and constraint on SOC flow"

   def storage_state(model, t):
       if t == model.T.first():
          return model.Z[t] == 0
       else:
          return (model.Z[t] == (model.Z[t-1] + (model.Ein[t]) - (model.Eout[t])))    
                     
   model.charge_state = Constraint(model.T, rule=storage_state)


   "Max SOC constraint" 
   def SOC_maxconstraint(model, t):
         return model.Z[t] <= model.Smax
   model.SOC_maxconstraint = Constraint(model.T, rule=SOC_maxconstraint)


   "Min SOC constraint"   
   def SOC_minconstraint(model, t):
        return model.Z[t] >= 0
   model.SOC_minconstraint = Constraint(model.T, rule=SOC_minconstraint)


   "Maximum dischage within a single hour"
   def discharge_constraint(model, t):
        return model.Eout[t] <= model.Rmax
   model.discharge = Constraint(model.T, rule=discharge_constraint)

   "Maximum charge within a single hour"   
   def charge_constraint(model, t):
        return model.Ein[t] <= model.Rmax
   model.charge = Constraint(model.T, rule=charge_constraint)


   "Limit discharge to the amount of the charge in the battery"
   def positive_charge(model, t): 
        return model.Eout[t] <= model.Z[t] 
   model.positive_charge = Constraint(model.T, rule=positive_charge)


  "Demand of energy constraint"
  def demand_constraint(model, t):
        return (model.L[t] == (df.loc[t, 'MktDemand'] + (model.Ein[t]) - (model.Eout[t]))) 
  model.demand_constraint = Constraint(model.T, rule=demand_constraint)


  "Non-negativity of total demand"
  def negativity_demand_constraint(model, t):
       return model.L[t] >= 0
  model.negativity_demand_constraint = Constraint(model.T, rule=negativity_demand_constraint)



  ## Objective function 

  original_costs = sum(df.loc[t, 'TOU'] * df.loc[t, 'MktDemand'] for t in model.T)

  model.costs = sum(df.loc[t, 'TOU'] * (df.loc[t, 'MktDemand'] + (model.Ein[t]) - (model.Eout[t])) 
  for t in model.T)

  model.objective = Objective(expr=model.costs, sense=minimize)

  results = SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model)




  print("Profits % =", round((model.objective() / original_costs ) * 100,2))
  print("Smax:", model.Smax.get_values().values())
  print("Rmax:", model.Rmax.get_values().values())
```

And I get:

```
  pyomo\core\expr\numvalue.pyx in pyomo.core.expr.numvalue.value()

  ValueError: No value for uninitialized NumericValue object Ein[0]
```

Do you guys know what I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally that means that your solver didn't get a result. So basically often if this is the error, your model is infeasible.

Maybe try to have a look at the solver information with tee=True.

solver = SolverFactory('glpk')

results = solver.solve(model,tee=True)

If it shows that your model is infeasible there is a problem with your constraints, or bounds or something (I didn't have a look at the equations)

Comment: I computed : solver = SolverFactory('glpk')

results = solver.solve(model,tee=True)    and I got this error message:                    
    Error: basis matrix is singular to working precision (cond = 4.9e+31)
    glp_intopt: cannot solve LP relaxation
    Time used:   84.2 secs
    Memory used: 67.6 Mb (70896367 bytes)
    Writing MIP solution to 
    'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpci7_50co.glpk.raw'...
    105133 lines were written

Comment: Did you try it with another solver ? For example cbc, if you have it installed on your computer. Or if not try using the neos server an Cplex solver :  "results = SolverManagerFactory('neos').solve(modele,opt='cplex',tee=True)"

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to build an ESS model? I mean the Energy Storage System.